# Invalid pseudocolumn error in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I was trying to search following query on SQL Server 2012 but when I use `@Val2` I get an error:

> Msg 126, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid pseudocolumn "$E500385".

If I use  `@Val1` it's working perfectly

Any ideas?

```
DECLARE @Val1 NVARCHAR(30) = '09064881'  
DECLARE @Val2 NVARCHAR(30) = '$E500385.MS3'  
DECLARE @SQL  NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE [F1] = '+@Val2 
EXEC(@SQL)

SET @SQL= 'SELECT * FROM <table>  WHERE [F2] = '+@Val1  
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put quotes around the variables if they contain text

```
SET @SQL= 'SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE [F1]='''+@Val2 + ''''
```